# I have a mysql query where I give value of a column in list " WHERE IN" and I want to order my result same order I give in list. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query where I give value of a column in list " WHERE IN" and I want to order my result same order I give in list. Is it possible?

My SQL query is like

```
SELECT * 
FROM <TABLE NAME> 
WHERE id IN (2,12,56,5,9)
```

I want the result to be in same order as I gave inside my list i.e. 2,12,56,5,9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE name IN (2,12,56,5,9)
ORDER BY FIELD(id,2,12,56,5,9)
```

Returns the index (position) of `id` in the 2,12,56,5,9 list. Returns 0 if str is not found.

If all arguments to FIELD() are strings, all arguments are compared as strings. If all arguments are numbers, they are compared as numbers. Otherwise, the arguments are compared as double.

[`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Comment: I wouldn't have sullied myself with the mundane solution. I recommend keeping your answer "tight" by deleting the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN id = 2 THEN 1
    WHEN id = 12 THEN 2
    WHEN id = 56 THEN 3
    ...
  END
```